# Get the value of children in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to get the value of cell in a table when the user click on the next cell?

```
<table id="registrarsTable">

<c:forEach items="${requestScope.AllUsers}" var="user" varStatus="loop">
    <tr class="userRow">
        <td class="numberWidth">${loop.index + 1}</td>
        <td class="nameWidth user" id="${user.userno}">${user.fullName}</td>
        <td>

         <button name="DeactivateBtn"  id="deactivate" class="deactivate btn">deactivate</button>

        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

in jquery I want to get the value of attribute "id" from second `td` when user click on deactivate button.

I make like this

```
var userNo = $('td.user', $(this).parents(".userRow")).attr('id');
```

and like this

```
      var userNo = $($(this).parent(".userRow") > "td").attr("id");
```

and no one works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#deactivate').click(function() {
    var userNo = $(this).parent().prevAll('td.user').attr('id');
});
```

From the button (which is `this`), traverse up to the parent (the `<td>` containing the deactivate button). Then, to the previous sibling `<td>` with the class `user`, and get the `id` attribute.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid relying on the fact the the deactivate button is in a `<td>` after the user name's `<td>`, you can do this:

```
$('#deactivate').click(function() {
    var userNo = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.user').attr('id');
});
```

Which finds the parent `<tr>` with `closest` and then the `<td class="user">` with `find`.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/Bk6ML/

API References:

- `parent()` - http://api.jquery.com/parent
- `prevAll()` - http://api.jquery.com/prevAll
- `closest()` - http://api.jquery.com/closest
- `find()` - http://api.jquery.com/find

Comment: The first way doesn't work, when alert userNo value it returns undefined, and when using closet in the second one, returns function does not exist !

Comment: The second example had a typo, which I corrected. See the working example.